# Ember view not being displayed

Tags: ember.js

I'm following this tutorial http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/flame-on-a-beginners-guide-to-emberjs.html

and unable to get the ReviewTextArea view to display.

My code so far is:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-0.9.6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    Hello <b>{{Songs.mixmaster}}</b>
</script>   

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view Songs.ReviewTextArea}}
</script>   

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
Songs = Em.Application.create({
    mixmaster: 'Andy',
    totalReviews: 0,
    ready: function() {
        alert('Ember sings helloooo');
    }
});

Songs.Song = Em.Object.extend({
    title: null,
    artist: null,
    genre: null,
    listens: 0
});


mySong = Song.create({
    title: 'Son of the Morning',
    artist: 'Oh, Sleeper',
    genre: 'Screamo'
});


Songs.ReviewTextArea = Em.TextArea.extend({
    placeholder: 'Enter your review',
});
```

However my browser (Chrome 22.0.1229.92) shows only the raw {{view ...}} tag in the page (using Inspect Element).

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: Does your console show an error ? If you could put the example in a jsfiddle it would be great.

Comment: It works with ember-1.0.pre.js, see the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rJEND/

Comment: @louiscoquio you fixed a mistake in your fiddle ;)... wow this has just been answered ;) The article contains a "coquille" :p

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot to mention it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your code - Song is not defined.

```
mySong = Song.create({
   title: 'Son of the Morning',
   artist: 'Oh, Sleeper',
   genre: 'Screamo'
});
```

It should be `Songs.Song`